# Rowspan has no effect on table heading

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created a mui table.
this table has two headings, out of which only one column will have it's values below. ie only second column with name `Heading2` will be having values below it.
`Heading1` doesn't have it's values below it.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";


const rows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    calorie: 10
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    calorie: 20
  }
];

export default function BasicTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 300 }} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {/* I want `Heading1` to occupy entire vertical column blow it */}
            <TableCell rowSpan={3}>Heading1</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Heading2</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row.id}>
              {/* this should display below `Heading2` */}
              <TableCell>{row.calorie}</TableCell> 
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Hence below `Heading1` it should occupy vertically the entire column and `Heading2` should display values. that is the requirement.
But right now 'Heading2's values are displayed under 'Heading1' column.

I have used `rowspan`, but it has no effect.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-table-rowspan-sofl-3465jo) working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add empty cell under `heading 1` to make empty cells under `Heading 1`:

```
<TableBody>
    {rows.map((row) => (
        <TableRow key={row.id}>
          {/* this should display below `Heading2` */}
          <TableCell></TableCell>
          <TableCell>{row.calorie}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    ))}
</TableBody>
```